# Using PDO raised exception "could not find driver"

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code I run this code :

```
private function dbConnection() {
        if (!is_resource($this->connessione))
            try {
                    $this->connessione = new PDO($this->db_type.":dbname=".$this->db_name.";host=".$this->db_server, $this->db_username, $this->db_pass );
                    //echo "PDO connection object created";
                    $this->setupSQLStatement();
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                    die();
                }
    }
```

It raised the exception "could not find driver". What is the driver and how to use it ?

Comment: What's your PHP version? You should have at least PHP 5.1.

Comment: I use w.a.m.p. 5 -> wamp5 info file shows : PHP version 5.2.1 ; Extensions chargées:...,PDO,... .

Comment: What's the value of `$this->db_type`?

Comment: After die-ing I got $this->db_type = mysql

Answer (score 4):

PDO comes with a core extension, and many "adapters" for some DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite...).

These adapters are additional extensions that you need to enable in `php.ini`, like this :

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_ibm.dll
;extension=php_pdo_informix.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll
;extension=php_pdo_user.dll
```

On a UNIX environment, replace .dll by .so.
Uncomment only adapters that you need (in the above example : MySQL).

Comment: I uncommented the lines but I always got `could not find driver` !

Comment: `php.ini` file in the `apache\bin` folder

Answer (score 1):

```
PDO::getAvailableDrivers()
```

Using this you can find available drivers in your server.

Comment: After making print_r , it shows : Array ( [0] => sqlite [1] => sqlite2 ). So how to make the connection ?

Comment: $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:/path/to/db/xyz.db');

Answer (score 1):

Add the following and check it outputs a 'mysql' line.

```
foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    echo $driver, '<br>';
```

If it doesn't then open php.ini and find:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Remove the `;`, so it looks like this and then retry:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Also do the same as above with:

```
;extension=php_pdo.dll
```