# PDO Could not find driver issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using the `laravel framework` and I am trying to get a colleagues project working on my own machine. 
When I try to load the project in my browser I get this error:

```
PDOException thrown with message "could not find driver"

Stacktrace:
#29 PDOException in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
#28 PDO:__construct in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
#27 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector:createConnection in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php:20
#26 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector:connect in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:59
#25 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory:createSingleConnection in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:47
#24 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory:make in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:127
#23 Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager:makeConnection in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:63
#22 Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager:connection in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:2782
#21 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:resolveConnection in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:2748
#20 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:getConnection in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1765
#19 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:newBaseQueryBuilder in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1681
#18 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:newQuery in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:628
#17 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:all in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\app\controllers\FollowController.php:6
#16 FollowController:showWhoToFollow in <#unknown>:0
#15 call_user_func_array in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:231
#14 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:callAction in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:93
#13 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:call in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:62
#12 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:930
#11 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in <#unknown>:0
#10 call_user_func_array in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:105
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:996
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:964
#7 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:738
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:708
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php:72
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php:47
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php:51
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:606
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in C:\wamp\www\sportskicker.tld\public\index.php:55
```

I cannot figure out what I can do to fix it. If anyone could provide some help it would be much appreciated. I am running `WAMP2.2` with `PHP v5.4.31`

Comment: You need to install it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561739/using-pdo-raised-exception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: I thought `PDO` was included with `PHP5.1+` and I've enabled the extensions in the `ini`.

Comment: Since you are using WAMP, you have 2 php.ini.  One for php that would be running in the command line and one for apache.  Check your `wamp/bin/apache<version>/bin/php.ini` file.  Also try running `phpinfo()` and ensuring you see it enabled.